# What the preparations and procedures to consider for circumnavigation?

Tags: flight-planning, navigation

If one wants to circumnavigate the planet in a general aviation airplane, how can one do it and what are the important issues to consider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Circumnavigating the planet Earth very popular *hobby* and a courageous endeavor. It is not an easy task and requires extensive preparation, planning and training.

**What is circumnavigation?**
Travelling around an island, a continent, or the entire world is called [circumnavigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumnavigation).

**What is considered global circumnavigation?**
Crossing all [meridians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography)) is not considered global circumnavigation. If you  walk completely around either Pole, you have crossed all meridians, but this is not generally considered a *circumnavigation*.

A basic definition is a route which covers at least one [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle), and it passes through at least one pair of points of [antipodal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodes) to each other.

**What are requirements for circumnavigation by airplane?**

- The route should start and finish at the same point.
- It should cross all meridians.
- The course must be at least 22,858.729 miles (36,787.559 kilometers) long. This is length of [Tropic of Cancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropic_of_Cancer).
- It must include set control points at latitudes outside the [Arctic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_Circle) and [Antarctic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Circle) circles.

[image: Earth]

**Do people do it?**
Yes, a lot of people do it. [Earth Rounders](http://www.earthrounders.com/) shares experiences of pilots who have flown around the world. It is categorized by engine types and solos etc.

**What should I need to know?**
A lot. Typically, people who flew around the world typically break their journey in 80-100 flights, or even more. It takes several months. Each flight of circumnavigation is significantly longer than a typical cross-country flight. It is much harder on many levels than an ordinary cross-country flight.

[This website](http://www.soloflights.org/comment_e.html) takes about the preparations thoroughly. It covers these section:

- The Pilot
- The Aircraft
- Preparation
- Survival equipment
- The flight

*Because of the longevity of this article, I am not duplicating it here as it contains all very useful information.*

**What are other people's experience?**
There are many people who have thoroughly documented their journeys, the preparations, the hazards and difficulties they faced, and many pictures and videos. I am listing a few, which certainly are not the best ones, but give a decent idea about their trip.

- [Robert Gannon](http://www.australianflying.com.au/news/cessna-pilot-completes-10-year-double-circumnavigation)
- [Carol Ann Garratt](http://www.earthrounders.com/cgi/archive/garratt/)
- [Flight Simulator X](http://kesaniemi.kapsi.fi/fs2004/)
  *Although this is in a simulation, but this trip is very thoroughly planned and it contains detailed path descriptions.*

Comment: Would a flight from A up a meridian to the north pole, down the opposite meridian to the south pole and then back up the original meridian to A qualify? (Ignoring the ridiculous terrain covered!)